# How to call a Java script function from Html Helper Class's script function?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, jqgrid, html-helper

I have a razor view, in which there is a function named getDocumentDetails. And I have written an html helper class that is following

```
     public static MvcHtmlString CreateJQGrid<T>(this HtmlHelper helper, GridViewModel<T> model)
    {
        bool blnEditIcon = false;
        bool blnEditRights = false;
        var htmlBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        // Place the Upload Button.
        if ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.UploadAction) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.AddNewAction)) && model.UserAccessRights != Constants.UserType.View)
        {
            htmlBuilder.AppendFormat(@"<div align='right' class='icon-list'>");
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.UploadAction) && model.UserAccessRights != Constants.UserType.Checker && model.UploadRights == true)
            {
                htmlBuilder.AppendFormat(@"<a class=""upload"" href=""{0}"" id=""Upload"">Upload &nbsp;&nbsp; </a>", model.UploadAction);
            }
            // Place the Add New Button
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.AddNewAction) && model.UserAccessRights != Constants.UserType.Checker)
            {
                htmlBuilder.AppendFormat(@"<a class=""addnew"" href=""{0}"" id=""AddNew"">Add New</a>", model.AddNewAction);
            }
            htmlBuilder.AppendFormat(@" </div><br /><br />");
        }
        htmlBuilder.AppendFormat(@"<div align='right' class='icon-list'>");

        if (!model.BulkApprovalRights)
            model.multiselectCheckBox = false;

        htmlBuilder.AppendFormat(@"</div>");


        htmlBuilder.AppendFormat(@"<table id=""{0}"" class=""scroll"" cellpadding=""0"" cellspacing=""0""></table>", model.Id);
        htmlBuilder.AppendFormat(@"<div id=""{0}Pager"" class=""scroll"" style=""text-align:center;""></div>", model.Id);

        htmlBuilder.AppendFormat(@"<script type=""text/javascript"">");

        htmlBuilder.AppendFormat(@" function EditingValidation(id) {{
                                           var selr = $('#{0}').jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow'); 
                                           var rowData = $('#{0}').getRowData(selr);
                                            if(rowData.Edit=='') 
                                            {{
                                                alert('You cannot edit the     selected record.'); return [false, ''];
                                            }}
                                          return [true, ''];                                       
   Rejected
                                }}", model.Id);
        //Md Aslam
        htmlBuilder.AppendFormat(@" function addLinkk(cellvalue, options,          
   rowObject) {{
                                          alert('AddLinkk');
                                return  '<a href=""#""  onclick=GridCellClick(""'+cellvalue+'"")><font color=""blue""><u>'+cellvalue+'</u></font></a>';

                                }}", model.Id);

        htmlBuilder.AppendFormat(@" function GridCellClick(cellValue) {{

                                        getDocumentDetails(); }}", model.Id);


        htmlBuilder.AppendFormat(@"function highlight (cellValue, options, 
  rowObject) {{ 
            if(cellValue=='Approved')               
                return '<span class=""label-
successforecolor"">'+cellValue+'</span>';
            else if(cellValue=='Rejected')               
                           return '<span class=""label-
  dangerforecolor"">'+cellValue+'</span>';
            else if(cellValue=='Pending')               
                           return '<span class=""label-infoforecolor"">'+cellValue+'</span>';
            else
                return cellValue;
                        }}");

        htmlBuilder.AppendFormat(@"$(function()");
        htmlBuilder.AppendFormat(@"{{");
        htmlBuilder.AppendFormat(@"var lastsel;");
        htmlBuilder.AppendFormat(@"$('#{0}').jqGrid({{", model.Id);
        htmlBuilder.AppendFormat(@"url: '{0}',", WebExtensions.GetUrlContent() + model.Url);
        //htmlBuilder.AppendFormat(@"editurl: '/InwardOutward/Edit',");
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.EditUrl))
            htmlBuilder.AppendFormat(@"editurl: '{0}',", WebExtensions.GetUrlContent() + model.EditUrl);
        htmlBuilder.AppendFormat(@"datatype: 'json',");
        htmlBuilder.AppendFormat(@"mtype: 'POST',height:280,");
        //Create Columns Names
        htmlBuilder.AppendFormat(@"colNames: [");
        foreach (var action in model.Actions)
        {
            htmlBuilder.AppendFormat(@"'{0}',", action.Name.ToString());
        }
        foreach (var column in model.Columns)
        {
            htmlBuilder.AppendFormat(@"'{0}',", column.Name.ToString());
        }
        htmlBuilder.AppendFormat(@"],");

        //Create Columns
        htmlBuilder.AppendFormat(@"colModel: [");

        foreach (var column in model.Columns.OrderBy(x => x.ActionOrder))
        {
            if (column.Name.ToUpper() == "REMARKS")
            {
                htmlBuilder.AppendFormat(@"{{name: '{0}', 
                                        index: '{1}', 
                                        align: '{2}', 
                                        search: {3},                                            
                                        sortable: {4},
                                        width: {5},                                             
                                        hidden: {6},
                                        sorttype: '{7}',
                                        sortable: true,
                                        searchoptions: {{sopt:[{8}]}},
                                        editable: {9},
                                        hidedlg: {10},
                                        edittype:'{11}',                                          
                                        editrules: {{custom: true, custom_func: EditingValidation}},
                                        classes: 'textInDiv',
                                        formatter: function (v) {{return '<div>' + $.jgrid.htmlEncode(v) + '</div>';}}
                        ", column.Index.ToString()
                      , column.Index
                      , column.Align == null ? "left" : column.Align.ToLower()
                      , column.IsSearch.ToString().ToLower()
                      , column.IsSortable.ToString().ToLower()
                      , column.Width > 0 ? column.Width : 100
                      , column.IsHidden.ToString().ToLower()
                      , column.SortType == null ? "string" : column.SortType.ToString().ToLower()
                      , column.SearchOptions == null ? "'eq','bw','bn','cn','nc','ew','en'" : column.SearchOptions.ToString().ToLower()
                      , column.IsEditable.ToString().ToLower()
                      , column.IsEditHidden.ToString().ToLower()
                      , column.IsEditTypeSelect == true ? "select" : "text"
                      );
            }
            else
            {
                htmlBuilder.AppendFormat(@"{{name: '{0}', 
                                        index: '{1}', 
                                        align: '{2}', 
                                        search: {3},                                            
                                        sortable: {4},
                                        width: {5},                                             
                                        hidden: {6},
                                        sorttype: '{7}',
                                        sortable: true,
                                        searchoptions: {{sopt:[{8}]}},
                                        editable: {9},
                                        hidedlg: {10},
                                        edittype:'{11}',                                          
                                        editrules: {{custom: true, 
   custom_func: EditingValidation}}"
                   , column.Index.ToString()
                   , column.Index
                   , column.Align == null ? "left" : column.Align.ToLower()
                   , column.IsSearch.ToString().ToLower()
                   , column.IsSortable.ToString().ToLower()
                   , column.Width > 0 ? column.Width : 100
                   , column.IsHidden.ToString().ToLower()
                   , column.SortType == null ? "string" : 
 column.SortType.ToString().ToLower()

                   , column.SearchOptions == null ? 
     "'eq','bw','bn','cn','nc','ew','en'" : 
      column.SearchOptions.ToString().ToLower()
                   , column.IsEditable.ToString().ToLower()
                   , column.IsEditHidden.ToString().ToLower()
                   , column.IsEditTypeSelect == true ? "select" : "text"
                   );
            }
            if (column.Index == "Status")
                htmlBuilder.AppendFormat(@",formatter:highlight
                                            }},");
            else
                htmlBuilder.AppendFormat(@"}},");
            if (column.IsEditable && !blnEditRights && 
  !string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.EditUrl))
                blnEditIcon = true;
        }
        htmlBuilder.AppendFormat(@"],");

        htmlBuilder.AppendFormat(@"loadtext: 'Loading {0}',", 
 model.Caption);
        htmlBuilder.AppendFormat(@"pager: jQuery('#{0}Pager'),", model.Id);
        htmlBuilder.AppendFormat(@" rowNum: 20,
                                    rowList: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 
  80, 90, 100, 200,500,1000,100000000],  
                                    loadonce: true,                                          
                                    ignoreCase: true,
                                    viewrecords: true,                                        
                                        ");

        //htmlBuilder.AppendFormat(@"multiSort: true,");                                   


        htmlBuilder.AppendFormat(@"caption: '{0}',", model.Caption);


        htmlBuilder.AppendFormat(@"pagepos: 'left',
                                   forceFit: true,
                                   autowidth: true,
                                   shrinkToFit: false,");
        htmlBuilder.AppendFormat(@"}});");

        htmlBuilder.AppendLine(@"");
        htmlBuilder.AppendLine(@"");
        htmlBuilder.AppendFormat(@"$('#{0}').jqGrid(", model.Id);
        htmlBuilder.AppendFormat(@"'navGrid', '#{0}Pager',{{ search: true, 
   add: false, edit: true, del: false, refresh: false, searchtext: 
  'Search',edittext: 'Edit',position: 'left'                                            
                                        ,", model.Id);

        if (blnEditIcon)
        {
            htmlBuilder.AppendFormat(@"edit: true, edittext: 'Edit'");
            //afterSubmit:function(response, postdata){{ alert('Coming');       
  var json   = response.responseText;var result = JSON.parse(json);return 
  [result.status,result.message,null];    }}
        }
        else
        {
            htmlBuilder.AppendFormat(@"edit: false,");
        }

        htmlBuilder.AppendFormat(@"
                                    }},");

        htmlBuilder.AppendFormat(@" {{ 
 afterSubmit:function(response, postdata){{  

 if(response.status == 200)
{{ 
$('.topinfo').html('<div   
          style=\'color:red\'>'+response.responseText+'</div>');

 var tinfoel = $('.tinfo').show();
  //tinfoel.delay(1500).fadeOut();
  return [true,''];
 }} else {{
  return [false,'error message'];
 }}
  }},
 onclickPgButtons:function(){{
 $('.topinfo').html('<div style=\'color:green\'> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>');
}}

 }},
                                     {{}},
                                     {{}},
                                    {{multipleSearch:true,  
   multipleGroup:true, showQuery: true,closeAfterSearch: true,searchOnEnter:          
    true}}");
        htmlBuilder.AppendFormat(@");");

        /* Add this line to include a separator between buttons */
        SeparatorBetweenButtons(model.Id, htmlBuilder);

        //Enable the Refresh
        htmlBuilder.AppendLine(@"");
        htmlBuilder.AppendLine(@"");
        htmlBuilder.AppendFormat(@"$('#{0}').jqGrid('navButtonAdd', '#{1}Pager', {{", model.Id, model.Id);
        htmlBuilder.AppendFormat(@"caption: 'Refresh',");
        htmlBuilder.AppendFormat(@"buttonicon: 'ui-icon-refresh',
                                    title: 'Refresh',");
        htmlBuilder.AppendFormat(@"onClickButton: function () {{");
        htmlBuilder.AppendFormat(@"$('#{0}').setGridParam({{ datatype:      
     'json' }});", model.Id);

        htmlBuilder.AppendFormat(@"$('#{0}')[0].clearToolbar();", model.Id);
        htmlBuilder.AppendFormat(@"$('#{0}').trigger('reloadGrid');", 
    model.Id);
        htmlBuilder.AppendFormat(@"}}");
        htmlBuilder.AppendFormat(@"}});");

        SeparatorBetweenButtons(model.Id, htmlBuilder);
        htmlBuilder.AppendLine(@"");
        htmlBuilder.AppendLine(@"");
        htmlBuilder.AppendFormat(@"$('#{0}').jqGrid('filterToolbar', {{ 
 searchOperators: true, defaultSearch:'cn' }});", model.Id);

        htmlBuilder.AppendFormat(@"  }}); ");
        htmlBuilder.AppendFormat(@"</script>");

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(htmlBuilder.ToString());

    }
```

In Which the Edit column contains the jqgrid formatter property, and called addLinkk function. In that addLinkk function, called the getDocumentDetails function which is in actual razor view file such that is razor file. While calling the getDocumentDetails, Its shows "getDocumentDetails is undefined".

The problem here is i can not call the function from the html helper class. And i don't know how to do it. please anybody help me.

My razor view is following.

```
  @using Intranet.Common;
   @using CSR.UI.Web.Helpers;
   @using CSR.Model;
  @using Intranet.Utilities;
 @model CorpGroupModel
 @{

  ViewBag.Title = "AddEditCorpGroup";
//Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
 }

 <div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">
        Manage Corporate Group </h3>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">

    <br />
    @Html.CreateJQGrid(Model.GridData)
</div>
   </div>

   <br/>

<div class="panel panel-default">
   <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title">
          Add / Edit Corporate Group</h3>
   </div>
   <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="icon-list">
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "ManageCorpGroup", null, new { @id     
   = "BackToList", @class = "backbtn" })
    </div>
    </br>
        @using (Html.BeginForm(Constants.Action.AddEditCorpGroup,       
   Constants.Controller.CorpGroup, FormMethod.Post, new { @role = "form" }))
    {

        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()          
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.IsAdd)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CompanyId);
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Status);         
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CreateUser);                                              
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CreateDate);
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.IsUserLoggedIn);
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.LoggedInUserSeq);
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.UserAccessRights); 
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.IsMakerRemarks)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.IsCheckerRemarks) 

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label for="" class="control-label">
                    Corporate Group Name </label><br />
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CorpGroupName, new { @class 
   = "form-control mand", @onkeypress = "return OnlyAlphaNumeric(this);", 
 @onkeyup = "return CPOnlyAlphaNumeric(this);" }).DisableIf(() => 
  Model.IsReadOnly == true)
            </div>
             <div class="col-md-4">
                <label for="" class="control-label">
                    Corporate Group Name </label><br />
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ManagingDirector, new { 
  @class = "form-control mand", @onkeypress = "return 
 OnlyAlphaNumeric(this);", @onkeyup = "return CPOnlyAlphaNumeric(this);" 
 }).DisableIf(() => Model.IsReadOnly == true)

            </div>
             <div class="col-md-4">
                <label for="" class="control-label">
                    Address1 </label><br />
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Address1, new { @class = 
 "form-control mand", @onkeypress = "return OnlyAlphaNumeric(this);", 
 @onkeyup = "return CPOnlyAlphaNumeric(this);" }).DisableIf(() => 
  Model.IsReadOnly == true)
            </div>
             <div class="col-md-4">
                <label for="" class="control-label">
                   Address2 </label><br />
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Address2, new { @class = 
 "form-control", @onkeypress = "return OnlyAlphaNumeric(this);", @onkeyup = 
 "return CPOnlyAlphaNumeric(this);" }).DisableIf(() => Model.IsReadOnly == 
  true)
            </div>
             <div class="col-md-4">
                <label for="" class="control-label">
                    Address3 </label><br />
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Address3, new { @class = 
 "form-control", @onkeypress = "return OnlyAlphaNumeric(this);", @onkeyup = 
 "return CPOnlyAlphaNumeric(this);" }).DisableIf(() => Model.IsReadOnly == 
  true)
            </div>
             <div class="col-md-4">
                <label for="" class="control-label">
                    Address4 </label><br />
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Address4, new { @class = 
 "form-control", @onkeypress = "return OnlyAlphaNumeric(this);", @onkeyup = 
 "return CPOnlyAlphaNumeric(this);" }).DisableIf(() => Model.IsReadOnly == 
 true)
            </div>
        </div>





        }       
   </div>
 </div>

<script type="text/javascript">

   // Start of  Hide Reset button in edit mode 


       var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))

     $(document).ready(function () {


  function getDocumentDetails()
   {

       alert("2");
   }

     });

  </script>
```

Comment: Wow, that method is making my eyes bleed lol.  It looks to me that you should be making better use of views and view models instead of building your HTML in code like that.  This is a bit of an aside from the question though.

Comment: What is the rendered output of your code when you run it?  Is the JavaScript code that it is creating actually valid?

Comment: what is your aim ? do you want to get model values inside js ?

Comment: Sorry for the late replay. No, inside the js set the json data to the model. The same page contains both grid and edit controls. If I click the edit button in the grid, then the grid's row data should populate on the field controls. So the row data will be in Json format right, i want to load this object to model.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with above comments posted to your question. Sorry Md Aslam, but which advantage has the usage of such "helper"?

You generate some code, which is bad to read, to extend, to modify and to verify. By the way I see that you create unneeded `class="scroll"` to `<table>` which is obsolete since 5 years.

You create **global** functions like `EditingValidation`, which will be assigned to `window` object and can have conflicts with other JavaScript code. The usage of the "helper" with two grids on the page will **overwrite the previous functions** like `EditingValidation`.

The code use *very specific options* like `rowNum: 20` and `height: 280` in the helper. Thus I don't see that one can really share the code.

You use `name`, which come from `column.Index`. In the way you can very easy produce errors like the values of `name`, which contains special characters like spaces or you can have more as one column with the same `name` value. The person, who would uses your code will think only about his abstract column model and can easy forget (or don't know at all) about some existing restrictions.

I would strictly recommend you to specify more clear your goals and to rewrite your code from the begin till the end. I would recommend you to write much more pure JavaScript code which can be easy read, be verified (in JSHint for example) and be easy debugged. You can use jqQuery events and column templates to share common code which you use and to make the usage of every specific grid very easy.